# Angularjs - multiple location.path() in the same $rootScope boolean

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, routes, rootscope

I'm creating my first single page app using Angular 1 (v1.6.0), utilizing `ng-hide` and `ng-show` to hide or show different header elements (my homepage has a parallaxed hero image in the header - my other pages do not).

For my controller, `routeController`, I was only able to assign one `$location.path()` per `$rootScope.showPortfolioHeader`:

```
app.controller('routeController', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.showPortfolioHeader = $location.path() === '/jcRealty';
}]);
```

I tried two ways to assign multiple paths to the same `$rootScope.showPortfolioHeader` boolean, which both failed:

**Try # 1**

```
app.controller('routeController', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.showPortfolioHeader = $location.path() === ('/jcRealty' || '/randomQuoteGenerator');
}]);
```

**Try # 2**

```
app.controller('routeController', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.showPortfolioHeader = $location.path() === '/jcRealty';
}]);

app.controller('routeController', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.showPortfolioHeader = $location.path() === '/randomQuoteGenerator';
}]);
```

Both of these attempts resulted in the boolean being applied to only one of the `$location.path()`'s. I then realized that in this case, I could accomplish what I want with:

```
app.controller('routeController', ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
            $rootScope.showPortfolioHeader = $location.path() !== '/';
    }]);
```

which applies `$rootscope.showPortfolioHeader` to any path that isn't the home page. **But I'd still like to know how to accomplish this without the `!==`, in case I had three distinct headers, etc etc.**

Comment: Please try to create plnkr for quick answers. Plnkr essentially helps avoid quesions like what version of angular, where is the controller etc. SOmetimes they also help isolate the problems yourself.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/fgTG7j?p=info Another problem I have is hash linking w/ routing. Make the Plunker preview window wide enough so nav menu (Home Portfolio Contact) appears at top. Scroll down to ‘Projects’, click ‘Project 1’. This opens a view and ng-show enables a new nav bar (which looks the same as the old). Look below <section ng-show="showPortfolioHeader"> in index.html for these nav anchors. From here I want ‘Portfolio’ and ‘Contact’ to link to the #portfolio and #contact hash links on my views/home.html view. But it only takes me to the correct route, not to respective hash links.

Comment: I was using this for reference: stackoverflow.com/questions/14712223/… As to my original question, I still need to spend more time figuring it out but hash linking from another view is now my top priority. Sorry for the delay.